# Error using the :GDiff command of fugitive.vim using gvim for windows and msys git 1.7.0.2

Tags: git, vim, msysgit, vim-fugitive

I've been using git along with fugitive.vim to manage code when I'm on windows. However, I've run into a problem. According to the [documentation](http://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/README.markdown), the :GDiff command should a diff window and allow me to stage only parts of a file. However, when I issue the command in a file with changes, I get the following error message:
[image]

Is this a problem with windows? vim? fugitive? msysgit? file permissions? Anybody know?

Comment: I'm having the *_exact_* same problem - please do let us know if/how you get this resolved!

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem - here's how I fixed it.

By default, Vim will try to store swap files beside the original. Fugitive creates a buffer that does not correspond to any real file path, so Vim barfs when it tries to create the swap file. The solution is to make sure that Vim has a path it *can* write to.

Here's how I fixed this:

```
if has("win32") || has("win64")
   set directory=$TMP
else
   set directory=~/tmp
end
```

Here's the original issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/9

**EDIT:**

As [fow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54928/fow) points out below, it's probably better to use something like the following:

```
set directory+=,~/tmp,$TMP
```

Vim should use the first path it can.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the `'directory'` option is a list of directories, and Vim will use the first one it can. It's best to simply add a value to the list rather than obliterate the whole thing, as in `set directory+=$TMP`. It's safe to do this without an OS check since `~/tmp` is added by default in Unix, and even if `$TMP` is empty on Unix, adding it will do nothing

Comment: @fow: +1 -- I do need to include `,` when I do `set directory+=`, right (since it's a comment delimited list)?

Comment: Also, try `set directory^=$TMP` (see [`:help :set^=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3Aset%5E%3D)).

Comment: @Chris Johnsen: Awesome; I was curious if I could do something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a Windows machine, but I was able to reproduce and isolate this problem on a Mac OS X 10.6 system.

Either create `C:\TMP` or `C:\TEMP` ([`:help 'directory'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27directory%27) says both are in the default value of the `directory` option on Windows builds of Vim), or add an *existing* directory to the value of the `directory` option.

I use a Vim-specific temporary directory under my home directory (again, no Windows here) and add two trailing slashes (`~/tmp/.vim-swaps//`). This kind of setting centralizes the swap files but gives them unique names based on the directories of the files being edited. See “Advantages” and “Disadvantages” in [`:help :swapname`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/recover.txt.html#%3Aswapname) as well as the 
“if a directory ends in two path separators” bit in [`:help 'directory'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27directory%27).

Use `^=` to prepend<sup>1</sup> your directory (so that it is always used, if it exists):

```
set directory^=C:\\some\\existing\\directory//
```

Or, use `+=` to append your directory (so that it is only used if it exists and no other applicable `directory` entries exist):

```
set directory+=C:\\some\\existing\\directory//
```

[Charles’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932399/error-using-the-gdiff-command-of-fugitive-vim-using-gvim-for-windows-and-msys-gi/5846751#5846751) suggests that `$TMP` (a reference to an environment variable) might be a good value for Windows:

```
set directory+=$TMP//
```

---

The root cause is related to the default value of the `directory` option combined with the pathname of `:Gdiff`’s index “pseudo” file.

The buffer for the index side of a `:Gdiff` view uses a special pathname that looks like `fugitive:///path/to/repository/.git//0/path/to/file/under/repository` (fugitive captures reads and writes to so named buffers and redirects them to the index by invoking Git “plumbing” commands).

The first entry in `directory` is usually `.`. This means that Vim will try to put the swapfile in the same directory as the edited file (i.e. `foo/bar.txt` will try to use `foo/.bar.swp`). If this preferred swapfile can not be created, then subsequent entries from `directory` will be tried.

With `.` as the first `directory`, the preferred swapfile for `fugitive:///path/to/repository/.git//0/path/to/file/under/repository` will be `fugitive:///path/to/repository/.git//0/path/to/file/under/.repository.swp`. The leading components of this pathname (`fugitive:`, `path`, `to`, etc.) probably do not exist, so Vim will go on to the next entry from `directory`. If none of the other `directory` entries are usable for creating swap files (e.g. they do not exist), then you get error E302.

I was able to reproduce your problem on a Unix-y system by using `set directory=.,~/no-such-dir,/var/no-such-dir,/no-such-dir` (i.e. taking the default Unix value and changing occurrences of `tmp` to `no-such-dir`). None of the “no-such-dir” directories actually existed. I got the same error when I use `:Gdiff`.

<sup>1</sup>
[`:help :set^=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3Aset%5E%3D) only says “add”, but the code shows that `set listopt^=…` prepends similar to how `set listopt+=…` appends (as the latter is documented to do). Both should automatically insert commas as needed (though there may have been bugs in this area).

Comment: i wonder why fugitive allows both read and write to those `fugitive:///path/to/repository/.git//0/path/to/file/under/repository` buffers? Why are they not read-only? In my case I can modify those buffers, and if I save them and then execute `git diff`, the output is affected.

Comment: @HảiPhong: Also try `git diff --cached`. With those pseudo-pathnames (the ones like `fugitive://…/.git//0/…`), editing and saving them is equivalent to directly changing the content that is staged for the next commit (i.e. Git’s “index”: stage 0). If you are confident in using the index to craft your next commit, it can be a powerful tool (like `git add` or `git reset` with `--patch`, but much more direct). If you do not like to use the index, you can “clear” its contents (make it match HEAD) with `git reset <pathname>` (or `:Gread -` in the buffer in question).

Comment: Wow, that explains it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That may be related to the [issue 428 of msysgit mentioned in my SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863038/gcommit-doesnt-work-with-fugitive-vim-under-windows-xp/2863166#2863166).

Try patching the `cmd/git.cmd` as I describe in my previous answer and see if this help.

Baring that, 2 options remains:

- either a locking problem (the file is locked by a process): an utility like [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) or [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) might help to see if it is the case (and what handle exactly there is on that swap file)
- or a Git issue. One good trick is then to install the net-installer of msysgit, which will build the latest version of Git on your Windows. You can then try and see if the problem persists with that updated version.
  Note: third option, trying to downgrade Git, again to rule out any link with that tool.

Comment: I already patched git.cmd, which did fix the earlier issue (thanks for that, by the way.

Comment: @Paul: I didn't realize that you were the one asking that previous question! ;)

Comment: I checked the swap files and it looks like vim is the only app with a handle for those files. I'm working on checking different versions of msysgit right now and I've also filed an issue on github.

Answer (score 1):

BTW same error I got, when I tried to :gdiff unsaved file - when i saved it (:w) it works!